# VS2017 - TF10169

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I have a small problem. I deleted project on azure devops. Then I deleted local directories. Now I still have "Detected: 1 delete(s)" in Pending changes. It is a delete operation for project dir.

I tried everything, I can't get rid of this pending change.
- I tried restoring dir, not helping.
- I tried to create the whole project again and promote the change.
- I tried deleting vs tfs cache

When I try to promote the change, I always get error TF10169: Unsupported pending change attempted...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `undo pending changes`? And if that doesn't work you can always try to `tf vc destroy` the item to get rid of it completely.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, undo pending changes gets an error, that project does not exists. But I will try that tf vc destroy tomorow and will get back to you.

Comment: I tried to tf destroy, but with no success. The project no longer exists. So it does nothing and I still have detected delete change.

Answer (score 1):

I think I finally got this working.

- I created project with same name as old one.
- I tried to map it to the old folder on local disk
- Then I tried to delte it all again and call tf destroy
- After that I deleted the project and the change was finally gone!!